# How to find the default username for a new Oracle install?

Tags: oracle

I just downloaded and installed Oracle 19, with the default settings for installing on a PC (non-server,) and SQL Developer.  SQL Developer detects two Oracle connections, called `LISTENER_ORCL` and `ORCL`, but I'm not able to connect to either one of them.  It keeps saying I have the wrong username or password.

I picked a memorable password that I'm certain I'm not getting wrong, so I can only imagine the problem is with my username.  SQL Developer is supplying the names of the connections as the username.  That doesn't work.  A bit of Googling suggests using "SYSDBA" as the default username.  That doesn't work either.  So... what exactly *will* work?  What do I have to do to connect to this database?

Comment: The default name for the "DBA account" is `SYS` in Oracle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name https://i.imgur.com/0OTep4x.png

Comment: What the error message says: you need to connect with the _role_ SYSDBA. I don't use it, but I think SQL Developer has some option to select that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks!  I put "SYS as SYSDBA" in the username field, and I got in.  Write this up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a list of user configured in an oracle database. SYS and SYSTEM are a few. SYS is the owner of most structures in the database and if you are here to find out how to connect to a database I strongly advise against using this account at all.

A slightly better account to use is SYSTEM, which is a dba account but can a do a bit less harm to the database. Use this account to create a regular user and use that to learn the database with.

If you can connect to the machine where the database is running, you can connect without a password. To do this you must be a member of the dba group. To connect set the ORACLE_SID variable to how it is defined during the database creation and use `sqlplus / as sysdba` to connect to your database.

Comment: "SYS" and "SYSTEM"?  That's not confusing in the slightest...

Comment: I can't help that but with these instructions you can create a user that fit's better to your taste. No problem.